# Do I call the base constructor when deriving from ServiceBase?

Tags: c#, .net

Microsoft .NET documentation for the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.servicebase) class constructor says:

> If you override the base class constructor, you should explicitly call
>   it in the constructor of your derived class.

In [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) in the Microsoft C# Programming Guide, it says:

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called
>   explicitly by using the base keyword, the default constructor, if
>   there is one, is called implicitly.

So do I need to call the base constructor explicitly or not, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  These compile to the same IL:

```
public class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1() : base() { }
}
public class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1() { }
}
```

I don't know why `ServiceBase` recommends explicitly calling it.  I'd go with the other suggestion, since it seems to make more sense.

Comment: Does the documentation's _"override the base class constructor"_ even make sense? Instance constructors are not really virtual, and they are not inherited, as far as I know. But of course, when there's only one accessible instance constructor in the base class, there's nothing you can do wrong (since you have to "chain" some base constructor). The documentation senetence may make sense in some .NET language other than C#? Or is it just pure nonsense?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's nonsense.